# Linking domain name to subdirectory without displaying subdirectory name in address

Tags: .htaccess, domain-name, directory

I've got a domain name, `blogdomain.com`, which I've linked to `otherdomain.com/blog` using this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?blogdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]
```

Now when I go to `blogdomain.com`, I'm redirected to `blogdomain.com/blog`. Is it possible to write a .htaccess rule so that I can avoid the subdirectory name appearing in the new address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]

I would suggest you to create a virtual host for blogdomain.com and point the document root to /blog/ directory

Comment: It's giving me a 500 error. I'm no good at .htaccess syntax so I can't tell what's going wrong. In what way does a virtual host help? Less for Apache to sort through?

Comment: What is your operating system/web server?

Comment: Heh... I'm using Apache2 on a Raspberry Pi, Raspbian OS. So for all intents and purposes it's Debian, just with an ARM processor. It's a toy server, of course, but it's had no hiccups yet.

Comment: Bam. Adding this line after the RewriteRule fixed it: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog` Which is odd - I don't know why it was still trying to redirect into the subdirectory, I was forcing it to go from blogdomain.com. Anyway, that's sorted. Thank you!

Comment: Im happy it worked for you :)